# How to use HTTPS with NSURLConnection?

Tags: iphone, https, nsurlconnection

I'm interested in HTTPS with `NSURLConnection`. Is it possible to send a request, respond to a challenge and load the secure URL?

Is there anything else that can be done with `NSURLConnection` via HTTPS?

Comment: What do you need to do? Have you read the docs?

http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://monsite/mapage.php"]
cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData
timeoutInterval:60.0];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setHTTPBody:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"score=222"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:YES];
NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

and then implement the appropiate delegate methods for NSURLConnection.

Answer (score 2):

NSUrlConnection works out of the box with HTTPS.  You do not have to do anything special.